# How to get a set of different month values from a particular date till today's date in hive

Tags: sql, datetime, hive, hiveql

I am trying to fetch a set of month values from a particular month.

Ex- If my starting date is 2011-11-05, then I want to have a set on months from 2011-11 till today's month(i.e. 2018-05).

```
It should look like this...
2011-11
2011-12
2012-01
2012-02
.
.
.
.
2015-01
.
.
2018-04
2018-05
```

I need this to set to map for active/inactive users for every month

Comment: hint use `add_months` for incrementing the date. And  `year` along with `month` functions to extract value. For documentation refer here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Comment: How you will pass the starting date, you are going to select the date from some table. I guess date will be passed dynamically and there is no table at all??? is it?

Comment: Well you can consider both scenarios. When I'm taking the date from a table or when I'm explicitly passing any random date. The main issue is to generate the set of months after that.

Comment: Which version of hive do you use?

Comment: I have updated the answer you can try this, and let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
select s.country,date_format(days_list,'YYYYMM') as year_month_list
from (
select  x.country,date_add (x.start_date,y.i) as days_list
from    (select 'Inida' as country, current_timestamp end_date,'2011-11-05' as start_date) x
        lateral view 
        posexplode(split(space(datediff(x.end_date,x.start_date)),' ')) y as i,k
) s
group by s.country,date_format(days_list,'YYYYMM');

Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
OK
Inida   201111
Inida   201112
Inida   201201
Inida   201202
Inida   201203
Inida   201204
Inida   201205
Inida   201206
Inida   201207
Inida   201208
Inida   201209
Inida   201210
Inida   201211
Inida   201212
Inida   201301
Inida   201302
Inida   201303
Inida   201304
Inida   201305
Inida   201306
Inida   201307
Inida   201308
Inida   201309
Inida   201310
Inida   201311
Inida   201312
Inida   201401
Inida   201402
Inida   201403
Inida   201404
Inida   201405
Inida   201406
Inida   201407
Inida   201408
Inida   201409
Inida   201410
Inida   201411
Inida   201412
Inida   201501
Inida   201502
Inida   201503
Inida   201504
Inida   201505
Inida   201506
Inida   201507
Inida   201508
Inida   201509
Inida   201510
Inida   201511
Inida   201512
Inida   201601
Inida   201602
Inida   201603
Inida   201604
Inida   201605
Inida   201606
Inida   201607
Inida   201608
Inida   201609
Inida   201610
Inida   201611
Inida   201612
Inida   201701
Inida   201702
Inida   201703
Inida   201704
Inida   201705
Inida   201706
Inida   201707
Inida   201708
Inida   201709
Inida   201710
Inida   201711
Inida   201712
Inida   201801
Inida   201802
Inida   201803
Inida   201804
Inida   201805
Inida   201812
Time taken: 2.184 seconds, Fetched: 80 row(s)
```